# How do user level threads (ULTs) and kernel level threads (KLTs) differ with regards to concurrent execution?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, operating-system

Here's what I understand; please correct/add to it:

In pure ULTs, the multithreaded process itself does the thread scheduling. So, the kernel essentially does not notice the difference and considers it a single-thread process. If one thread makes a blocking system call, the entire process is blocked. **Even on a multicore processor, only one thread of the process would running at a time, unless the process is blocked.** I'm not sure how ULTs are much help though.

In pure KLTs, even if a thread is blocked, the kernel schedules another (ready) thread of the same process. (In case of pure KLTs, I'm assuming the kernel creates all the threads of the process.)

Also, using a combination of ULTs and KLTs, how are ULTs mapped into KLTs?

Answer (score 22):

Your analysis is correct.  The OS kernel has no knowledge of user-level threads.  From its perspective, a process is an opaque black box that occasionally makes system calls.  Consequently, if that program has 100,000 user-level threads but only one kernel thread, then the process can only one run user-level thread at a time because there is only one kernel-level thread associated with it.  On the other hand, if a process has multiple kernel-level threads, then it can execute multiple commands in parallel if there is a multicore machine.

A common compromise between these is to have a program request some fixed number of kernel-level threads, then have its own thread scheduler divvy up the user-level threads onto these kernel-level threads as appropriate.  That way, multiple ULTs can execute in parallel, and the program can have fine-grained control over how threads execute.

As for how this mapping works - there are a bunch of different schemes.  You could imagine that the user program uses any one of multiple different scheduling systems.  In fact, if you do this substitution:

> Kernel thread  <--->  Processor core
>
> User thread <---> Kernel thread

Then any scheme the OS could use to map kernel threads onto cores could also be used to map user-level threads onto kernel-level threads.

Hope this helps!

Comment: But, Some sites and books say that ULT cannot take the advantage of multiprocessing and one of your lines say "On the other hand, if a process has multiple kernel-level threads, then it can execute multiple commands in parallel if there is a multicore machine." Where Am I going wrong ?

Comment: Can you provide a link to that? That sounds incorrect.

Comment: Please check these 2 links http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582876/what-does-it-mean-by-user-threads-cannot-take-advantage-of-multithreading-or-mu and http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1065/what-is-the-difference-between-user-level-threads-and-kernel-level-threads . Last line of 2nd link says that. I searched up a bit more and I think it depends on 1:1 model . Please correct me, if I am missing any major info. Thanks !!

Comment: That first question has an answer that says Wikipedia is likely wrong. And I'm not sure about the second - that seems flatly contradicted by, say, JVMs that use ULTs and absolutely run in parallel.

Comment: Actually, I am getting more clarity from your answer. That borrow some KLT's and if you are using a multicore, then offcourse they can execute parallely . That line in you explaination makes more sense. So, Am I right here that they can be made parallel ? Thanks for bearing :)

Answer (score 4):

Before anything else, [templatetypedef](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791801/how-do-user-level-threads-ults-and-kernel-level-threads-klts-differ-with-reg/14792010#14792010)'s answer is beautiful; I simply wanted to extend his response a little.

There is one area which I felt the need for expanding a little: **combinations of ULT's and KLT's**.  To understand the importance (what Wikipedia labels [hybrid threading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_%28computer_science%29#M:N_.28Hybrid_threading.29)), consider the following examples:

Consider a multi-threaded program (multiple KLT's) where there are more KLT's than available logical cores.  In order to efficiently use every core, as you mentioned, you want the scheduler to switch out KLT's that are blocking with ones that in a ready state and not blocking.  This ensures the core is reducing its amount of idle time.  Unfortunately, switching KLT's is expensive for the scheduler and it consumes a relatively large amount of CPU time.

This is one area where hybrid threading can be helpful.  Consider a multi-threaded program with multiple KLT's and ULT's.  Just as **templatetypedef** noted, only one ULT can be running at one time for each KLT.  If a ULT is blocking, we still want to switch it out for one which is not blocking.  Fortunately, ULT's are much more lightweight than KLT's, in the sense that there less resources assigned to a ULT and they require no interaction with the kernel scheduler.  Essentially, it is almost always quicker to switch out ULT's than it is to switch out KLT's.  As a result, we are able to significantly reduce a cores idle time relative to the first example.

Now, of course, all of this depends on the threading library being used for implementing ULT's.  There are two ways (which I can come up with) for "mapping" ULT's to KLT's.

1. A collection of ULT's **for all** KLT's

   This situation is ideal on a shared memory system.  There is essentially a "pool" of ULT's to which each KLT has access.  Ideally, the threading library scheduler would assign ULT's to each KLT upon request as opposed to the KLT's accessing the pool individually.  The later could cause race conditions or deadlocks if not implemented with locks or something similar.
2. A collection of ULT's **for each** KLT ([Qthreads](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?tp=&arnumber=4536359))

   This situation is ideal on a distributed memory system.  Each KLT would have a collection of ULT's to run.  The draw back is that the user (or the threading library) would have to divide the ULT's between the KLT's.  This could result in load imbalance since it is not guaranteed that all ULT's will have the same amount of work to complete and complete roughly the same amount of time.  The solution to this is allowing for ULT migration; that is, migrating ULT's between KLT's.

Comment: I am looking for other example libraries/APIs that implement "hybrid threading".  If anyone knows of any, please feel free to comment or edit them in.

Comment: +1 for pain you took to write this long for others. Isn't Pthread library an example of hybrid threading ?

Comment: The original Linux PThreads library as well as the IBM-backed proposed replacement NGPT (Next Generation POSIX Threads) were m:n threading implementations. However, Linus Torvalds said that if Linux kernel threads are too fat, the correct solution is not to layer more complexity on top of them in userspace, but rather to make them leaner and faster, and so they did, and the current NPTL (Native POSIX Threading Library) won, which is a 1:1 library. In the BEAM Erlang VM, one VM per CPU core is fired up, each in a separate thread, and Erlang processes are scheduled between them.