# Mapping User-level threads and Kernel-level threads

Tags: multithreading, operating-system

How are User-level threads mapped to Kernel-level threads?

Comment: Something wrong with the answer to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791801/how-do-user-level-threads-ults-and-kernel-level-threads-klts-differ-with-reg?rq=1

Comment: User-level threads are almost useless, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It varies by implementation. The three most common threading models are:

1. 1-to-1: Each user-level thread has a corresponding entity that is scheduled by the kernel.
2. n-to-1: Each process is scheduled by the kernel. Thread scheduling takes place entirely in user space.
3. n-to-m: Each process has a pool of entities that are scheduled by the kernel. These are assigned to run particular user-level threads by a user-space scheduler that is part of the process.

Modern implementations are almost all 1-to-1.

Comment: ya, modern implementations are almost 1-1, but i can understand this point, when am using wither `pthreate_create()-linux` or `CreateThread()-windows` or `thr_create()-solaris`. But am not clear, how `start()` api from `Thread` class internally works with linux/windows/solaris platforms as per provided  jdk code(..\openjdk\hotspot\src\os\)

Comment: In code `openjdk\hotspot\src\os\solaris\vm\os_solaris.cpp` it is `if (noofLWPS < (Threads::number_of_threads() + 2)) {
        thr_setconcurrency(thr_getconcurrency() + 1);
      }`

Comment: @David can I do not map user-level thread to kernel thread？Realize user-level multithreading by switching the work of different threads by implementing the scheduler in the user process

Comment: @David just use the time slice which provided to process

Comment: @MelvinLevett That's the n-to-1 approach. It has huge downsides. First, you can't ever do two computations at once, negating much of the benefit of threading. Second, if you hit a page fault or the like, all threads are stalled.

Answer (score 0):

There's a bit of confusion about the terminology used for referring to ULTs and KLTs.
Following are the two different interpretations. Please correct me if I got this wrong:

1. KLTs are needed to achieve concurrency in the kernel (Note the interpretation of Kernel as a Process or a live entity). This is true about Micro kernels like Symbian, where a kernel thread is responsible for every hardware resource of the system (e.g File Server, Location Server, Calendar Server, etc). However, in a kernel like Linux, which is mostly a library (and not a process or a living entity on its own), there's really no meaning for Kernel threads. In Linux, every thread you create is treated by the Kernel as a process and Kernel always runs either in the Process context or the Interrupt context.
2. Second interpretation is based on whether Threading (or concurrency) is visible to the Kernel or not. For instance, using setjmp, longjmp one can achieve concurrency at user space. Like already discussed, Kernel is totally unaware of this. This concurrency may be termed as ULT. And the thread whose creation the Kernel is aware of (one using Clone() system call) may be called KLT.