# Does user level threads take advantage of multiprocessing?

Tags: multithreading, process, operating-system, multiprocessing

Does user level threads take advantage of multiprocessing ? I read one such answer here. But, it's not clear though.

[What does it mean by "user threads cannot take advantage of multithreading or multiprocessing"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25582876/what-does-it-mean-by-user-threads-cannot-take-advantage-of-multithreading-or-mu)

And one other answer here says that it is possible

[How do user level threads (ULTs) and kernel level threads (KLTs) differ with regards to concurrent execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14791801/how-do-user-level-threads-ults-and-kernel-level-threads-klts-differ-with-reg)

Am I missing something here with some important details ?

Answer (score 4):

Usually, `user-level threads`, cannot take advantage of multiprocessing whereas, `kernel-level threads` can take advantage of it.

It simply means that we can run several `kernel-level threads`, in parallel on a `multi-core` computer system. But the same cannot be done for `user-level threads`.

This is possible because `kernel-level threads` are managed by the `Operating System`, whereas, the `user-level threads` are managed by the user, meaning the OS is only aware of single `user-level thread`(the executing one), even when there are actually more than one.

Now in your links, you provided it is mentioned that:

```
Some implementations base their user threads on top of several kernel 
threads, to benefit from multi-processor machines (M:N model).
```

From what I understood after reading the links is that its possible for `user-level threads` to take advantage of `multiprocessing`, only if its **implementation specific**. So this would basically be like a `kernel-level thread` associated with a `core` and a `user-level thread` associated with the respective `kernel-level thread`.

So in the end, its after all the `kernel-level threads` running parallel on `several cores(OR CPU's)`. We can't take advantage of `multiprocessing` without any assistance from `kernel`.

Comment: Ok ! So, making it little bit precise . What actually the 2nd link says, that if you borrow some kernel level threads, then user level threads can be made to work like a 1:1 model. This is it ?

Comment: @JonSillick Yup. Indirectly, they are talking about one to one model.

Comment: @JonSillick But remember that is only implementation specific.

Comment: I have never seen real-world thread implementation in which multiple user threads executed within a single kernel thread. Obviously, an application can do that by creating kernel threads through system services and user threads within those kernel threads through library calls. However, this model is theoretical.

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon how you define "take advantage."

User threads are scheduled by the process.
The process is scheduled by the kernel.

A user thread can then only execute on the process in which the process is scheduled.

Thus a user threads from the same process cannot execute on multiple processors concurrently. They execute interleaved.

If that is your definition of multi-processing, your answer is NO.

However, if the OS supports it, the process can execute on any available processor. Thus, a user thread can execute on any available processor.

If that is your definition of multi-processing, your answer is YES.

Answer (score 0):

in m:1 model user threads map to one kernel thread. so user threads cannot run simultaneously on multiple cores. but in m:n model user threads map to many kernel threads when kernel threads can run on multiple cores and therefore user threads can run on multiple cores and take advantage of multiprocessing.